# Positioning different sets of entries next to each other in python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter

I use a Tkinter frame in python, and on one of the pages I need to display 2 sets of entries, one next to the other, where the number of entries is equal to the number in range (in the full program is a changing variable, so each time the number of entries changes). I use the for loop to do it.

However, when I try to pack the entries into the frame, the 2 sets of 3 entries are shown in one single column of 6 entries, instead of showing 2 columns with 3 rows of entries each.

If I adjust the packs to the left and right sides of the frame, each set of entries then is shown in 1 row, and has 3 columns, which is not needed.

When I use .place or .grid instead of .pack, then for each set only one single entry is shown (I guess all 3 entries are just placed in a single defined location ex. (x = 550, y = 80), so that 3 entries "overlap" into one)

I guess I need to write a more sophisticated "for loop" function and use .grid or .place positioning, so that all 3 entries will be displayed in a column one after the other.

Or I'm also thinking that using .pack and inserting the entries into a new frame inside the first frame, and then position these 2 frames one next to another might work. But again, I tried to create an extra frame inside the first page, and it didn't work.

Any observations and tips would be highly appreciated!

Here is the full code, so you might try playing around with it and see the whole picture. (sorry for a mess in imports, I also have to sort it out)

P.S. It is a part of a bigger code, where I need to use more then 1 page, so this code is the smallest that works - if I there would be only a single frame in the program, I would have no problem arranging the entries as I need. The problem is that I don't know how to arrange the entries is this particular structure.

```
import tkinter as tk                
from tkinter import font  as tkfont 
import traceback
from tkinter import messagebox
from pandastable.core import Table
from pandastable.data import TableModel

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

import tkinter as Tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class MyTable(Table):
    """
      Custom table class inherits from Table.
      You can then override required methods
     """
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        Table.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)
        return


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        self.geometry('800x600+200+100')
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)


        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button2.place(x = 20, y = 50)

        entries = [Entry(self, font =('Calibri', 7 )) for _ in range(3)]
        for entry in entries:
            #entry.place(x = 400, y = 80)
            entry.pack()

        entries_date = [Entry(self, font =('Calibri', 7 )) for _ in range(3)]
        for entry in entries_date:
            #entry.place(x = 550, y = 80)
            entry.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would help if you could reduce the code down to a [mcve]. If you're asking about placing widgets in a single frame, there's no need for two pages and all of the code necessary to switch between the pages. All we need is a frame and the code you're using to fill the frame with widgets. You can also remove most of the imports, since you only need tkinter and maybe ttk to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks Brayan for your feedback! It is a part of a bigger code, where I need to use more then 1 page, so this code is the smallest that works - if there would be only a single frame in the program, I would have no problem arranging the entries as I need. The problem is that I don't know how to arrange the entries is this particular structure.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. If the question is laying out widgets in a frame, it doesn't matter if that frame is the only frame or one of thousands. The solution will be the same. All of the other code just makes it harder for us to reproduce. The class `PageTwo` is completely irrelevant to the problem -- it's not laying out any entries, or using the entries in any way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create rows and columns, there are two generally accepted ways to do it:

1. make each row a frame, and pack the entries along a side
2. use grid to create rows and columns.

The first is best if your columns don't need to line up, the second is best if your columns *do* need to line up.  Though, you also have to take into consideration what else you're putting in the frame -- you can't use both `grid` and `pack` on widgets that have the same master.

Note: If you're creating identical widgets in each row, then as a side effect the columns will line up even when you use pack.

Example using pack:

```
entries = []
entry_frame = Frame(self)
entry_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
for column in range(3):
    entry = Entry(entry_frame, font=('Calibri', 7))
    entry.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    entries.append(entry)

entries_date = []
entry_date_frame = Frame(self)
entry_date_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
for column in range(3):
    entry = Entry(entry_date_frame, font=('Calibri', 7))
    entry.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    entries_date.append(entry)
```

Example using grid:

```
entries = []
for column in range(3):
    entry = Entry(self, font=('Calibri', 7))
    entry.grid(row=0, column=column, sticky="ew")
    entries.append(entry)

entries_date = []
for column in range(3):
    entry = Entry(self, font=('Calibri', 7))
    entry.grid(row=1, column=column, sticky="ew")
    entries_date.append(entry)
```